# Is there a way to scaffold a singleton resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources

The regular way of scaffolding doesn't work if you are working with a singular resource, is there any way to get default singular controllers through scaffolding? Say if a user has only one post is there an easy was to run a command like:

```
rails g scaffold post -singular
```

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the scaffold options in Rails 3.1.1, you will see the following:

```
Usage:
  rails generate scaffold NAME [field:type field:type] [options]

Options:
  ...

ActiveRecord options:
  ...

Rspec options:
  [--singleton]                 # Supply to create a singleton controller
```

The output of `rails g scaffold Post name:string body:text --singleton` is

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20111103072825_create_posts.rb
  create    app/models/post.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/post_spec.rb
   route  resources :posts
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
  invoke    haml
  create      app/views/posts
  create      app/views/posts/index.html.haml
  create      app/views/posts/edit.html.haml
  create      app/views/posts/show.html.haml
  create      app/views/posts/new.html.haml
  create      app/views/posts/_form.html.haml
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb
  create      spec/views/posts/edit.html.haml_spec.rb
  create      spec/views/posts/new.html.haml_spec.rb
  create      spec/views/posts/show.html.haml_spec.rb
  invoke      helper
  create        spec/helpers/posts_helper_spec.rb
  create      spec/routing/posts_routing_spec.rb
  invoke      rspec
  create        spec/requests/posts_spec.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/posts_helper.rb
  invoke      rspec
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/posts.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/posts.css.scss
  invoke  scss
identical    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
```

So it seems that the scaffolding generates the usual view templates.

In Rails 3.0 this was an option for the whole generator, not only the one for Rspec. See the [Railscast 216 for Generators in Rails 3](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3). Perhaps you will find a generator in Rails 3.0.x that will fulfill your needs.

Comment: hmm it looks like in the documentation provided in the link that you would have to pass the option -c, --singleton in order for this to work. However when I typed that into the command line it ran the regular type of scaffold generator.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this so I created a [Github issue](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/issues/274). Follow this if it helps. However I found the only way to fix this is to manually fix the problem. That means change the names by hand. I know you don't want to do that but I found some times that is the only way.